# Connecting to a Socket from Android application

Tags: android, sockets

I am developing an android application where i need to connect to a server socket from my application. The application works fine when i am at home and my android phone and the server using the same Wi-Fi. However, when I am at the university my application can not connect to the server socket. It always shows "The Operation has timed out Error".

Obviously I have changed the code to make sure if i am connecting using the right IP Address.

Can anyone give me some suggestions please.

thanks
kaisar

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it's working fine at home, but not other places, it would lead me to believe the wifi you're connected to at school may be blocking people from accessing other sites on certain ports. This isn't uncommon. If you're not using wifi, your wireless provider may be doing the same thing.

When you're at home, try turning off wifi and going through the cell network and see what results you get.